# form validation Not Working Django and print just on message

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django form validation is not working. It only prints the following message: 
     form is not valid!

I am a Django beginner and I am having trouble figuring out why this is happening.

mycode in form.py:

```
efrom django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple
from blog.models import Category
from wsgiref.validate import validator


class PostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, min_length= 1,)
    slug = forms.SlugField(allow_unicode=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    banner = forms.ImageField()
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects)
    authors = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects, 
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PostForm, self).clean()
        slug = cleaned_data['slug']

    if not "sepehr" in slug:
        raise forms.ValidationError("here we have some errors !")
    return cleaned_data
```

and my code in views:

```
class HoemView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog2/create.html'
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        context = {
            'form':form
         }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
         form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
             return HttpResponse('form is valid!')

        return HttpResponse('form is not valid!')
```

Answer (score 1):

All you are seeing is 'form is not valid!' because that is all your view is returning in the HttpResponse.

Change the last line from:

```
return HttpResponse('form is not valid!')
```

to:

```
return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

That should show you what your errors are.